# Closing form and capture closing event

Tags: c#, forms, sender

everyone.
I've run into such a problem. In my app, I show second form from my main form through ShowDialog method. In this form I have some textBox(s) to connect to the DB and a Connect button. If user clicks X, the app exit. But if user click "connect" - I connect to DB and also close my second form. To catch closing event I use FormClosing method where the app asks whether I'm about to close the app and if yes it exit. The problem is that when I click the button, FormClosing event fires and asks me if I want to exit. How to avoid it? I try to use sender, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         orcl.connect(userID.Text, Password.Text, comboTNS.Text);

         if (orcl.ifHasRows("select dbclass from setupdbversion where dbclass='SECURITY' and rownum=1"))
         {//my stuff
             this.Close();
         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
     };
}


private void SecConnForm_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{   
     MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
     if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
          if (string.Equals((sender as Form).Name, @"SecConnForm")) //it doesn't work as in any cases the sender is my form, not a button (when i click on button of course)
          {
               if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Really exit?", "Closing...",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                       == DialogResult.Cancel) 
                   e.Cancel = true;
               else
                   Application.Exit();

          }
          else
          {
               //other stuff goes..
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: "when i click the button", please elaborate which button you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form closing event will fire every time form is closed whether that is done by code or by user click.

What you need is something similar to this.

```
private boolean bFormCloseFlag = false;

private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         orcl.connect(userID.Text, Password.Text, comboTNS.Text);

         if (orcl.ifHasRows("select dbclass from setupdbversion where dbclass='SECURITY' and rownum=1"))
         {//my stuff
             bFormCloseFlag = true;
             this.Close();
         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
     };
}


private void SecConnForm_FormClosing_1(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{   
     if (bFormCloseFlag = false)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
          if (string.Equals((sender as Form).Name, @"SecConnForm")) //it doesn't work as in any cases the      sender is my form, not a button (when i click on button of course)
          {
               if (MessageBox.Show(this, "Really exit?", "Closing...",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                       == DialogResult.Cancel) 
                   e.Cancel = true;
               else
                   Application.Exit();

          }
          else
          {
               //other stuff goes..
          }
       }
     }
}
```

This flag will simply check whether form is closed by 'X' button click or it is closed by your code.

Answer (score 0):

The this.Close() triggers the closing type of "UserClosing"
Possibly just hide the dialog instead of this.close()?

Comment: you could add comment to convey your message anyway :-)